# Developing an API project

Tags: youtube-api

I recently created a project and the scripts were working fine.
Then the stopped loading the requests.

I looked at my dashboard to find there were several days with 10,000+ queries
which didn't make any sense.

I created a new key and restricted access to the IP only.

I changed the key on all of my scripts and it still does not display like it was.

Any suggestions about what to try next?

Thanks

Comment: Try writing a character to a file every time a request is made. That way, the size of that file will show how many requests were made on that computer.

Comment: I have a file that is created upon every request, on the browser. It will grab the browser ID. Only my testing has created a file. Its been more then 24 hours and the request is still dead. I have had no luck getting to speak to support.

Comment: I will pay for a support plan, but it does not allow me to get past the "organization"